# Why am I getting: TypeError: this.tenantQueryParamResolve is not a function

Tags: typescript, angular, promise

## Steps to reproduce

I have an Angular 2 TypeScript service, running in a Angular 1 / Angular 2 hybrid environment, designed to capture a URL parameter (tenant) and use this parameter to set up a component attribute.

This service is required to bridge the fact that the $routeParams, or a similar,  service is not available in this environment.

The service has two methods:

- **setTenantQueryParam** - Called from the Angular 1 controller with the *$routeParams* service and used to resolve a promise with the parameter name.
- **getTenantQueryParam** - Called from the Angular 2 component requesting the parameter value. It returns a promise that is resolved the the *setTenantQueryParam* above is called.

This is the code:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class MigrationHelperService {
    tenantQueryParam: string;
    tenantQueryParamResolve: (x: string) => void;

    setTenantQueryParam(tenant: string) {
        this.tenantQueryParam = tenant;
        this.tenantQueryParamResolve(tenant);
    }

    getTenantQueryParam(): Promise<string> {
        if (this.tenantQueryParam !== undefined) {
            return Promise.resolve(this.tenantQueryParam);
        }
        else {
            let deferred = Q.defer<void>();
            return  new Promise<string>(
                function (resolve) {
                    this.tenantQueryParamPromiseResolve = resolve;
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

## Observed Behavior

This software breaks executing:

```
this.tenantQueryParamResolve(tenant);
```

with the following message:

```
angular.js:13550 TypeError: this.tenantQueryParamResolve is not a function
    at MigrationHelperService.setTenantQueryParam (http://localhost:8080/iq/ng2/util/MigrationHelperService.js:31:26)
    at new eval (http://localhost:8080/iq/js/app.js:5703:36)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8080/iq/js/appVendor.js:16322:14)
    at $controller (http://localhost:8080/iq/js/appVendor.js:21772:28)
    at link (http://localhost:8080/iq/js/appVendor.js:45012:26)
    at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/iq/js/appVendor.js:21336:9)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/iq/js/appVendor.js:20735:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/iq/js/appVendor.js:20039:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/iq/js/appVendor.js:19919:30)
    at lazyCompilation (http://localhost:8080/iq/js/appVendor.js:20257:25) <div id="view" ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

## Expected Behavior

The assignment

```
this.tenantQueryParamPromiseResolve = resolve;
```

in the *getTenantQueryParam* method works, setting up *tenantQueryParamResolve* correctly.

I suspect this is a problem with scope within the *getTenantQueryParam*; I've tried a number of alternatives to no avail. It is time someone who knows what they are doing help me out!

Thanks in advance for your help. Sincerely, Rodrigo.

## Postscript Note

I added a try / catch block on the  *this.tenantQueryParamPromiseResolve = resolve;* assignment:

```
try {
    this.tenantQueryParamPromiseResolve = resolve;
}
catch(err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
}
```

The assignment is failing! with the following message:

```
Failed to assign
MigrationHelperService.ts:75 TypeError: Cannot set property 'tenantQueryParamPromiseResolve' of undefined
    at eval (MigrationHelperService.ts:71)
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:584)
    at MigrationHelperService.getTenantQueryParam (MigrationHelperService.ts:67)
    at LoginComponent.ngOnInit (loginComponent.ts:32)
    at DebugAppView._View_LoginComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (LoginComponent_Host.template.js:34)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (view.ts:243)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.ts:345)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (view_ref.ts:93)
    at eval (downgrade_ng2_adapter.ts:105)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17064)
```

Went one step further and added an attempt to access *this.tenantQueryParamPromiseResolve* prior to the attempt to set it:

```
try {
    console.log("typof: " +  +  typeof this.tenantQueryParamResolve)
    this.tenantQueryParamPromiseResolve = resolve;
}
catch(err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
}
```

and got the following:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'tenantQueryParamResolve' of undefined
    at eval (MigrationHelperService.ts:70)
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:584)
    at MigrationHelperService.getTenantQueryParam (MigrationHelperService.ts:66)
    at LoginComponent.ngOnInit (loginComponent.ts:32)
    at DebugAppView._View_LoginComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (LoginComponent_Host.template.js:34)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (view.ts:243)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.ts:345)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (view_ref.ts:93)
    at eval (downgrade_ng2_adapter.ts:105)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17064)
```

It appears that *this.tenantQueryParamResolve* is not scoped! Reading on TypeScript it appears that this is associated with the function hence it makes sense. This said, how can I access the service *tenantQueryParamResolve* from within the promise function? I've tried all possible incantations and my magic wand is out our power!

Answer (score 0):

Because you just declare `tenantQueryParamResolve` without initializing it. The error will be gone if you put something like this in your `MigrationHelperService`'s constructor:

```
this.tenantQueryParamResolve = (x: string) => { console.log(x); }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as I expected, a scope issue. I solved it by declaring *tenantQueryParamResolve* as static, with the final working product being:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class MigrationHelperService {

    /*
     * This is a helper service to be used to capture the route’s tenant query
     * parameter in the NG1 SignInController and make it available in the LoginComponent
     * to enable it to show / hide the tenant form control.
     * TODO: replace it with NG2 route management when the time is right.
     */
    private tenantQueryParam: string;
    private static tenantQueryParamResolve: (x: string) => void;
    private static tenantQueryParamPromise: Promise<string>;

    constructor() {
        MigrationHelperService.tenantQueryParamPromise = new Promise<string>(
            function (resolve) {
                MigrationHelperService.tenantQueryParamResolve = resolve;
            }
        );
    }

    public setTenantQueryParam(tenant: string) {
        this.tenantQueryParam = tenant;
        MigrationHelperService.tenantQueryParamResolve(tenant);
    }

    public static getTenantQueryParam(): Promise<string> {
        return MigrationHelperService.tenantQueryParamPromise;
    }
}
```